# I have 6 wan connections, what's the best way to load balance them?

Tags: wide-area-network, connections

5 diferent companies are going to share the same building, and each one of them have one internet link. I have to use all of the links because of bureaucracy stuff. My server only have 4 LAN boards. What's the best solution for this scenario? I have an Extreme X460 Switch and I'm using PFSense!

Is it possible to do link aggregation in the Extreme before the link arrive on the PFSense?

Thanks and sorry for my poor English!

Answer (score 2):

Unless these companies merge, you should let each companie use their own router with their public IP

That will allow them to create their own VPN tunnel and most importantly they will be separated.

If you really need only one router you should use one that support VLAN tagging per port and that support all those IP. You create the routing rule (vlan vs what public ip they use) I dont know if pfsense allow that

Comment: The problem is: they are going to be mixed all over the building, and those are sister companies. If the companies were separated by floors or something I could separate the infrastructure.
I think the solution is going to be more network cards for the server, link aggregation on the switch + vmware

Comment: +1 for vlan and though MAC spoofing is a thing I would filter on MAC to help with future diagnostics - not sure you need more network cards as long as your OS supports VLAN and virtual interfaces eth0:1 eth1:3 things like that.